# At what point does decreasing solvent temperature cause a decrease in gas solubility?

Tags: physical-chemistry, solubility

Example: At constant pressure, carbon dioxide becomes less soluble in water as temperature increases. We also know that carbon dioxide becomes more soluble in water as temperature decreases.

Does introduction of order and loss of kinetic energy of solvent molecules eventually lead to a decrease in a solvent's ability to accommodate gas molecules? It is hard for me to believe that ice cubes can hold gas more effectively than the same volume of a glass of water.

Comment: Intuitively I would expect ice to hold gas MORE than liquid water could, as ice is less dense. Perhaps for the majority of substances which get MORE dense as they freeze, your assumption would make sense to me...
Of course, I'm going off intuition, not data, so I could be wrong.

Comment: @iammax: You are reasoning by analogy. Any gas becomes practically insoluble in anything at the phase transition into the solid solvent. There is no space for a random gas molecule in a crystal lattice of similarly sized host molecules. Exceptions: Chladathes and hydrogen, at elevated pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules such as "solubility of A in B rises with lower temperature" are only meant to be used if there is no phase transition of the participating substances.